# MySQL Query Assistance -> Multiple WHERE clauses?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the database tables as shown below.

What I am looking to do is get all records of colourschemes where colour_1, colour_2, colour_3, colour_4, colour_5 matches any of users' user_colour_1, user_colour_2 or user_colour_3 entries by agent_id.

Basically a user is signed up by an agent and then dictates what colours they like. The colourschemes (a business user) sign up on their own and dictates what colours they cater for. I need to find, for a particular agent, whether *any* colourschemes' colours are catered for *any* of the users colours they chose.

```
----------------------
agents
----------------------
agent_id  | agent_name
--------- | ----------
1         | Rod
2         | Jane
3         | Freddy

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
users
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
user_id | agent_id | user_name | user_colour_1 | user_colour_2 | user_colour_3
------- | -------- | --------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
1       | 1        | Andy      | 1             | 2             | 3
2       | 2        | Betty     | 2             | 1             | 5
3       | 3        | Claire    | 3             | 1             | 6
4       | 1        | Derek     | 4             | 5             | 7
5       | 1        | Eric      | 1             | 6             | 2
6       | 2        | Fay       | 2             | 7             | 3
7       | 3        | Gary      | 3             | 1             | 7
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------
colourschemes
----------------------------------------------------------------
scheme_id | colour_1 | colour_2 | colour_3 | colour_4 | colour_5
--------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | --------
1         | 1        | 2        | 3        | 5        | 7
2         | 2        | 3        | 5        | 1        | 4    
3         | 3        | 6        | 7        | 2        | 4    
4         | 4        | 3        | 1        | 7        | 2
5         | 5        | 6        | 7        | 2        | 3
6         | 6        | 5        | 1        | 4        | 3
7         | 7        | 3        | 6        | 1        | 2

-----------------------
colours
-----------------------
colour_id | colour_name
--------- | -----------
1         | red
2         | yellow
3         | blue
4         | green
5         | orange
6         | purple
7         | black
```

OK and sorry to be so long but here are the wanted results...

```
------------------------------------------
results table
------------------------------------------
agent_id | user_id | scheme_id | colour_id
------------------------------------------
1        | 1       | 1         | 1
1        | 1       | 1         | 2
1        | 1       | 1         | 3
1        | 1       | 2         | 2
1        | 1       | 2         | 1
1        | 1       | 2         | 3
1        | 1       | 3         | 3
1        | 1       | 3         | 2
1        | 1       | 4         | 3
1        | 1       | 4         | 1
1        | 1       | 4         | 2
1        | 1       | 5         | 2
1        | 1       | 5         | 3
1        | 1       | 6         | 1
1        | 1       | 6         | 3
1        | 1       | 7         | 3
1        | 1       | 7         | 1
1        | 1       | 7         | 2
1        | 4       | 1         | 5
1        | 4       | 1         | 7
1        | 4       | 2         | 5
1        | 4       | 2         | 4
1        | 4       | 3         | 7
1        | 4       | 3         | 4
1        | 4       | 4         | 4
1        | 4       | 4         | 7
1        | 4       | 5         | 5
1        | 4       | 5         | 4
1        | 4       | 6         | 5
1        | 4       | 6         | 4
1        | 4       | 7         | 7
1        | 5       | 1         | 1
1        | 5       | 1         | 2
1        | 5       | 2         | 2
1        | 5       | 2         | 1
1        | 5       | 3         | 6
1        | 5       | 3         | 2
1        | 5       | 4         | 6
1        | 5       | 4         | 2
1        | 5       | 5         | 6
1        | 5       | 5         | 1
1        | 5       | 6         | 1
1        | 5       | 6         | 2
1        | 5       | 7         | 6
1        | 5       | 7         | 1
1        | 5       | 7         | 2
```

Comment: Could you also list a table of your expected results? its unclear as to what you're looking for.

Comment: Please read - stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. As @paqogomez points out, you need to include more detail, and less fluff. And have you attempted any code?

Comment: That's extremely broad, you're asking for someone to create an entire site for you. Or are you asking for help with a specific part?

Comment: If a match is found that should be listed. Therefore, the resulting table could have multiple user_id's returned, and also a user_id may appear more than once for each time one of their colour choices matches one of the colourschemes available colours.

Comment: Please show us an example based on your current data.

Comment: @Parker It's just a tiny part of a much larger site. The client has just dropped this _great_ idea.

Answer (score 0):

What you look for is a complex where clause like this.

```
SELECT 
  u.agent_id, 
  u.agent_name 
from 
  users u, 
  colourschemes c 
where 
  u.user_colour_1 = c.scheme_id  
  or  u.user_colour_2 = c.scheme_id 
  or u.user_colour_3 = c.scheme_id 
  and c.colour_1 = "blue"     
  and c.colour_2 = "purple" 
  and c.colour_3 = "black" 
  and c.colour_4 = "yellow" 
  and c.colour_5 = "green" ;
```

Comment: You need to put parens around your `and` and `or` logic.  As written this would not return what you expect.  I'd recommend using SQL92 standard (`inner join`) instead of the older syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've just noticed the hole in my db design above regarding missing the user_colour_id reference in the colourschemes table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just to follow up, here is the suggested code from another source of advice...

```
SELECT u.user_id
     , u.agent_id
     , s.scheme_id
     , u.user_colour_1 AS user_colour
  FROM users u
 INNER JOIN colourschemes ON (u.user_colour_1 = s.colour_1 OR u.user_colour_1 = s.colour_2 OR u.user_colour_1 = s.colour_3 OR u.user_colour_1 = s.colour_4 OR u.user_colour_1 = s.colour_5)
UNION ALL
SELECT u.user_id
     , u.agent_id
     , s.scheme_id
     , u.user_colour_2 AS user_colour
  FROM users u
 INNER JOIN colourschemes ON (u.user_colour_2 = s.colour_1 OR u.user_colour_2 = s.colour_2 OR u.user_colour_2 = s.colour_3 OR u.user_colour_2 = s.colour_4 OR u.user_colour_2 = s.colour_5)
UNION ALL
SELECT u.user_id
     , u.agent_id
     , s.scheme_id
     , u.user_colour_3 AS user_colour
  FROM users u
 INNER JOIN colourschemes ON (u.user_colour_3 = s.colour_1 OR u.user_colour_3 = s.colour_2 OR u.user_colour_3 = s.colour_3 OR u.user_colour_3 = s.colour_4 OR u.user_colour_3 = s.colour_5)
```